# Fetching the data from device and saving it to the sql duplicate entries

Tags: sql-server

I am fetching the data from a device and saving it in the db but everytime I fetch it, it replicates the data with the previous one already saved in the db. Hence, increasing the size of the data (useless one) in the db.

Fetching:

```
if (listInfo != null && listInfo.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var p in listInfo)
    {
        db.DL.Add(p);
    }
}
```

How do I change this so it only saves the unique data and not saves what is already in db.

Lets say I fetch all the 3124 records from the device now, but I dont want to store all of them to db. I only want to store the newest (last one `2017-11-29 13:37:47.000` in this case) and the db should have 3124 records not 6247 (which is happening now)

Comment: define key in `p` which makes it uniqe. So, if `p`'s key is some ID field (or combination of two or more fields), EF will check if that ID exists. If it does, record will be updated. If not, it will be inserted like in your case

Comment: Can you paste how you retrieve listInfo before that code block?

Comment: @Nino lets say I have DateTime in sql db and i am also fetching DateTime from the device, now when I am going to store it to the db should I make it like this? if (db.D1L.Any(x => x.DateTime == p.DateTime)) continue;

Comment: @Isma check pls

Comment: @Isma everytime I fetch the records from the device it brings all the data inside it, I am then storing all the data in db for faster processing (later on) but everytime I save it, it saves all the data again and again where I only want to save the data which is NOT in db.

Comment: I think registrationId is the unique id of the record on the device, right? See @Vaibhav shetty answer but use the registrationId field, if it is not unique then you need to also use the date.

Comment: @Isma I cannot use the RegID since a single RegID may have used the device multiple times, I want the latest record saved on the basis of latest date (which comes from the device) and is obviously not present in db,

Comment: db.D1L.Any(x => x.DateTime == p.DateTime) didn't work for you?

Comment: @Isma no, please check the updated ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to save only new records given the column "DateTime".

You could retrieve the latest record from your db ordered by date:

```
var lastRecord = db.D1Log.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then filter your list to process only newer records:

```
if (lastRecord != null)
{
    listInfo = listInfo.Where(x => x.DateTime > lastRecord.DateTime).ToList();
}
```

Finally, add the new records to the db, you don't need to count before the foreach as if you have 0 records the foreach will exit right away, also it is better to save everything after the foreach has executed instead of saving on each iteration.

```
foreach (var p in listInfo)
{
    db.D1Log.Add(p);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check before saving(with primary key), if record exists don't save

```
if (listInfo != null && listInfo.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in listInfo)
                {
                    if (db.D1Log.Any(x => x.PrimaryKey == p.PrimaryKey )) 
                    continue;

                    db.D1Log.Add(p);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Comment: no need to check all columns, just check with primary key, here will check if record with that key is there or not , if not present in database table, then only we will insert new record, Please update "PrimaryKey" with actual one, i just gave an example

Comment: you can check with RegistrationId
if (db.D1L.Any(x => x.RegistrationId== p.RegistrationId)) continue;

OR you can do
if (db.D1L.Any(x => p.DateTime  > x.DateTime )) continue;

Comment: It does not work either, It skip pasts the loop and does not add any record at all.